# Limit checkboxes with simple form

Tags: jquery, simple-form

Im using the Simple form gem to setup a form on my rails app. I have a list of checkboxes (about 20 options) and i want to limit the user to selecting only 3. How can i achieve this?

View:

```
<%= f.association :interests, :as => :check_boxes, :label => false %>
```

First part of the Rendered HTML

```
<div class="control-group check_boxes optional">
  <div class="controls">
    <label class="checkbox">
        <input class="check_boxes optional" id="user_interest_ids_1" name="user[interest_ids][] "      
         type="checkbox" value="1" />Adventure Sports</label>
   <label class="checkbox">
       <input class="check_boxes optional" id="user_interest_ids_2" name="user[interest_ids][]"  
       type="checkbox" value="2" />Arts and Crafts</label>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably would go with jQuery to deal with this :

```
$(":checkbox").click(function(){
  $length = $(":checkbox").length();
  if ( $length > 2 ) {
    $(":checkbox:checked").attr("disabled", true);
  } else {
    $(":checkbox").removeAttr("disabled");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').change(function(e){
   if ($('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length > 3) {
        $(this).prop('checked', false)
   }
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Uan5M/

Comment: Try this if you want something more advanced maybe useful for other cases http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/GFCKA/

Comment: so this answer is better than the one below?

Comment: @js111 I recommend this one which is faster, but you can try both of them. it depends on you.

Comment: ok thanks, cant seem to get it to work... added the first 2 boxes of the rendered HTML above..how should i change it?

Comment: Hi.  I can't seem to get this to work either.  When I click on "checking" any of the checkboxes, it doesn't show up as "checked" on the html.  I am not sure if that is the cause?

Comment: @ming Hi, can you elaborate, please?

Comment: @undefined.  Thanks for the quick reply.  When I click on one checkbox, I would look at the source code and even though I checked one of the boxes, it doesn't show as "checked" on the source code until after I save the changes.  Not sure if that is the cause of it not working?  Thank you!

Comment: @undefined To clarify, the `<input class="check_boxes optional"` doesn't change to "checked" until after I save the changes.